# 2D isometric game with 3D prefabs

Tags: unity

Is it possible to have a **2D isometric** game in Unity, but also have **3D prefabs** in the scene?

Will that work or should I make the game in **3D** with an **isometric** camera?

Comment: You can do this, but depending on the look you have in mind, you might find it trickier to layer 3D content correctly against 2D. For instance if you have a 3D prop on two adjacent tiles, and you want the lower prop to draw in front of the upper prop. But in scene space, they're both on the same xy plane, so they intersect like they're beside each other instead of overlapping with one behind the other. There are work-arounds, but you might find it easier and more Intuitive to just work in true 3D space with a camera/sprites set up to give that isometric look.

Comment: My aim is to make a game like. clash of clans so would a 3d scene. be better

Comment: Myself, I would do that with a 3D scene.

Comment: You have pretty good intuition, most 2D games in Unity are essentially 3D games where everything is represented by quads or 3D models shown top-down through an isometric camera. If you have tried pushing the 2D/3D button on the top of the scene UI window, you may notice that basically this basically just switches your scene camera from perspective to orthographic. The only real difference in Unity when you create a 2D or 3D project is the default packages that Unity imports. In terms of isometric games, you probably want to work in 3D since it's a bit easier and less math work with than 2D.

Comment: If someone answers your question, remember to click the check mark on their answer. It lets them know that their efforts were successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Unity allows you to combine 2D sprites and 3D meshes in the same scene without any problems.

The only thing that's separate are the 2D and 3D collision systems. 2D colliders won't interact with 3D colliders and vice versa, but you can attach 2D colliders to meshes or 3D colliders to sprites if you want to.

So you might want to decide early whether you want 2D or 3D physics in your game.

Comment: How do I import the 3d mesh into my scene without it looking dark or looking flat

Comment: By adding some light sources to your scene. When you have any more problems, feel free to ask a new question with a screenshot, a more detailed description of what you did and a description of how you want it to look.

Comment: How do i add a light source to brighten things u

Comment: @elliot727 https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LightingOverview.html - when you have any specific problems, please ask a new question.